# Android paid app, free download for publisher?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Is there some way I can publish a paid app on the Android Market (Google Play) and then maybe specify an gmail address from which it's free to download? I want to download my own app From the market Onto my device, but not having to make a payment for it.

(With the licensing service from android you have something similar, you can specify exceptions for certain addresses from which the market is accessed.)

Comment: If it's your app, you have the apk. What's the issue?

Comment: I want to be secure that it will be downloaded correctly from the market, pretty much just like a final test. This way i'd be able to make sure that everything works as expected (i.e. i might stupiditly have uploaded the wrong apk).

Comment: Can't you just use the "refund within 15 minutes" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load the final version of the app to your device and verify.